# Flutter How do I disable the Drawer-Item corresponding to the Page I am currently on

Tags: flutter

so I have a Drawer with currently two Drawer-Items leading to Page1 and Page2. Lets say I am currently on Page1. I can still press the Drawer-Item "Page1" and another "Page1" will be opened. I don#t want this to happen, therefore my question.
How do I disable Drawer-Item "Page1" when I am currently on Page1 and Drawer-Item "Page2" if I am on Page2.
Thank you in advance.

```
class PrimaryDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrimaryDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Neuigkeiten'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
              return const NewsPage(title: 'Neuigkeiten');
              }));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Geburtstage'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
              return const BirthdayPage(title: 'Geburtstage');
              }));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: So i added a code snippet, so whats bothering me is that If I am on the "NewsPage" and I open up the Drawer I can open up "NewsPage" again, I want to prohibit that. IDK if it even matters if there is the same page multiple times in the Route, but It just bothers me, probably a me thing i guess.

Comment: Please add more  details to discuss, what kind of implementation you follow please put your code snippet to more discuss.

Comment: @Jafarashrafi If more details are needed lmk

Answer (score 0):

before navigate to new Page2 close the Drawer

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: Not a solution to this question, but you helped me with another question, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use provider to save your current page index and put condition while clicking on drawer item to check if its current page index is 1 then Page 1 will be not clickable and drawer is closed after the same